# Сравнение всех файлов между собой из директории

Tags: python, файлы

Привет. Я хотел бы сравнить все файлы из разных папок между собой и найти те файлы, содержание которых одинаковое. Например, в первой папке есть два файла Spam1.txt, Spam2.txt. Первый содержит строку Spamspamspam, второй - нет. И есть ещё одна папка с файлом Spam3.txt, в котором так же есть строка Spamspamspam. Я пока ещё не определил как сравнить файл с каждым из своей директории, а потом еще и с файлами других директорий. Возможно есть некие методы обхода элементов? Извините за, возможно, плохую формулировку, описал как смог.
UPD: Вопрос решился с помощью метода cmpfiles из модуля filecmp.

Comment: `filecmp.cmpfiles()` сравнивает файлы с одинаковыми именами. У вас же имена разные `Spam1.txt`, `Spam3.txt`. Если никакой из ответов из дубликата для вас не работает, то опишите в вопросе, чем результаты от желаемых отличаются (если вопрос другой, я переоткрою).

Comment: Да, ответ их дубликата оказался верным, но меня интересует, есть ли что-то попроще. Например, в документации по модулю filecmp указано что атрибут same_files объекта dircmp указывает на идентичность двух файлов по их содержани, а мне как раз нужно найти файлы с одинаковым содержанием. Возможно, я что-то упускаю, тк английский хромает.